# Docker-Compose won't install on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

Most guides that I found to install Docker Compose on Raspbian resolve around an installation via pip, e.g.

```
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

Unfortunately, if I try that on my Raspberry Pi 3, it fails with the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi-2:~/docker-compose $ sudo pip3 install docker-compose
Collecting docker-compose
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/41/fec934f6b895fab91eb73c9253aae1446fcf7512b6e5a2fa0e7b99d080d7/docker_compose-1.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests<3,>=2.20.0 (from docker-compose)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/c1/24814557f1d22c56d50280771a17307e6bf87b70727d975fd6b2ce6b014a/requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docker[ssh]>=5 (from docker-compose)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docker[ssh]>=5 (from docker-compose) (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.7.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.6.0, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.3, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.4.3, 4.4.4)
No matching distribution found for docker[ssh]>=5 (from docker-compose)
```

This seems to be a rare problem, as I could not find other reports of this complication.

Comment: Are you able to re-create the same error with a current **and** supported version of the OS. Raspbian Buster replaced Raspbian Stretch in 2019. RaspiOS 32-Bit Buster replaced Raspbian in 2020.

Comment: what version of docker is installed?

Comment: Having the same version with `Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289`. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue because the OS is a bit outdated. The version 1.28+ requires a library not available.
simple solution install the latest 1.27

`sudo pip3 install "docker-compose<1.28"`